# php массив данных из базы - как отследить изменение?

Tags: php, oracle

Смысл проблемы.
Есть запрос и массив, на основе которого выполняется ещё один запрос, что то типа такого:

```
$row = oci_parse($conn, "Select * from table");
oci_execute($row, OCI_DEFAULT);
       while ($get_result = oci_fetch_assoc($row)){
        $result=$get_result;
    $NPP_ROW=$result["OTD_NPP"];

$row2 = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT * from table2 table2.ID=:NPPUSL");
    oci_bind_by_name($row2, ':NPPUSL', $NPP_ROW);
oci_execute($row2, OCI_DEFAULT);
       while ($get_result2 = oci_fetch_assoc($row2)){
        $result2=$get_result2;
        $NPP_CARD=$result2["NPP"];
}}
```

Нужно сделать проверку if на изменение значения в переменной $NPP_ROW во втором запросе. Что-то типа:

```
 if ($NPP_ROW!=$result["OTD_NPP"]) {
$i=1;
echo $I;
}
else 
{$i=$i+1;
echo $i;
}
```

Тут счетчик, смысл в том, чтобы при изменении переменной счетчик сбрасывался. Подскажите как такое реализовать?

Comment: ну а в чем проблема реализовать так как вы написали?

Comment: проблема в том, что при проходе while значение переменной меняется и в итоге условия всегда $NPP_ROW=$result["OTD_NPP"]. Как при таких условиях сохранить значение из первого while, чтобы оно было доступно для следующего?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$row = oci_parse($conn, "Select * from table");
oci_execute($row, OCI_DEFAULT);
$LATEST_NPP = false; // false on first iteration
while ($get_result = oci_fetch_assoc($row)){
    $result=$get_result;

    $NPP_ROW=$result["OTD_NPP"];

    $row2 = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT * from table2 table2.ID=:NPPUSL");
    oci_bind_by_name($row2, ':NPPUSL', $NPP_ROW);
    oci_execute($row2, OCI_DEFAULT);
    while ($get_result2 = oci_fetch_assoc($row2)){
        $result2=$get_result2;
        $NPP_CARD=$result2["NPP"];
        if ($LATEST_NPP == $NPP_ROW || !$LATEST_NPP){
            // переменная не изменилась или первая итерация
        }
        else {
            // первая изменилась 
        }

    }
    $LATEST_NPP = $NPP_ROW;

}
```

Comment: Помогло, если кому понадобится, чуть модифицированный вариант:                                                                                                  if ($LATEST_NPP != $NPP_ROW){
            $i=1;
echo $i;
    }
        else {
               $i=$i+1;
   echo $i;
        }
  $LATEST_NPP = $NPP_ROW;